# Как передвинуть mesh в openGL следующим образом:

Tags: c++, opengl

У меня есть куб, состоящий из 6 плоскостей. Все эти плоскости я генерирую в XY координатах и затем располагаю их путем трансформации матриц.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно повернуть этот куб вокруг глобальных осей и затем передвинуть плоскость корректно.

Я покажу, что мне нужно и что у меня есть сейчас.
Я могу повернуть куб
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем мне нужно передвинуть одну из плоскостей правильно, взависимости от поворота куба. Но плоскости все равно двигаются по глобальным осям и я не могу имплементировать передвижение согласно повороту.
Красная линия показывает как плоскость двигается сейчас, зеленая линия показывает как она должна двигаться
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я создаю куб. Все вершины в плоскости в диапазоне (0,0) - (2, 2);

```
    planeXY.setupMesh();
    planeXY.setOrigin({1, 1, 1});
    
    planeXY1.setupMesh();
    planeXY1.setOrigin({1, 1, 1});
    planeXY1.moveAlongGlobalAxis(QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 2.0));
    
    planeZY.setupMesh();
    planeZY.setOrigin({1, 1, 1});
    planeZY.rotate(QVector3D(0.0f, -90.0f, 0.0f));
    planeZY.moveAlongGlobalAxis(QVector3D(-2.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    
    
    planeZY1.setupMesh();
    planeZY1.setOrigin({1, 1, 1});
    planeZY1.rotate(QVector3D(0.0f, -90.0f, 0.0f));
    
    planeXZ.setupMesh();
    planeXZ.setOrigin({1, 1, 1});
    planeXZ.rotate(QVector3D(90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    planeXZ.moveAlongGlobalAxis(QVector3D(0.0, -2.0, 0.0));
    
    planeXZ1.setupMesh();
    planeXZ1.setOrigin({1, 1, 1});
    planeXZ1.rotate(QVector3D(90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
```

Mesh.cpp

```
void Mesh::moveAlongGlobalAxis(QVector3D coordinates)
{
    QMatrix4x4 identityMatrix;   
    identityMatrix.translate(coordinates);
    position += coordinates;
    this->translationMatrix = identityMatrix * translationMatrix;
}

void Mesh::moveAlongLocalAxis(QVector3D coordinates)
{   
    this->moveAlongGlobalAxis(coordinates); 
}

void Mesh::rotate(QVector3D rotation)
{
    QMatrix4x4 identityMatrix;
    
    identityMatrix.translate((-1) * this->position + this->origin);
    identityMatrix.rotate(rotation.x(), QVector3D(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    identityMatrix.rotate(rotation.y(), QVector3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
    identityMatrix.rotate(rotation.z(), QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
    identityMatrix.translate(this->position - this->origin);
    this->rotationMatrix =  identityMatrix * this->rotationMatrix;
}


void Mesh::setOrigin(QVector3D origin)
{
    this->origin = origin;
}

const QMatrix4x4 Mesh::getModelMatrix() const
{
    
    return translationMatrix * rotationMatrix;
}
```

Эту функцию я хочу имплементировать и не понимаю как:

```
void Mesh::moveAlongLocalAxis(QVector3D coordinates)
{   
    this->moveAlongGlobalAxis(coordinates); 
}
```

Я знаю, что для перемещения как я хочу мне нужно повернуть куб обратно, передвинуть, и затем повернуть снова, но я не могу сделать это, потому что я не могу сохранить повороты меша из-за моих первых трансформаций, где я поворачиваю плоскости для получения куба. Поэтому, я хочу знать, как трансформировать объекты в OpenGL правильно и как достичь результата, который я описал выше

Comment: Вопрос-дежавю. Наверное стоит почитать какой-нибудь ликбез по аналитической геометрии.

Comment: @user7860670 Это конечно круто, вот только где бы я информацию не рыл, везде пишут одно и то же, наизусть уже знаю, что к чему. Если есть источник, где наглядно показывают что происходит с объектом при множестве трансформаций во всех возможных комбинациях, буду рад

Comment: Вряд ли, учитывая, что количество комбинаций бесконечно. В такой ситуации наверное будет сподручнее делать каскад преобразований: например посчитать матрицу преобразования для центра куба, и затем матрицу преобразований для каждой грани с центром куба в качестве начала координат, затем их перемножать.

Comment: @user7860670 Так проблема у меня не совсем с трансформациями. У меня все вертится и крутится как нужно. Мне не особо понятно, как мне плоскость передвинуть после вращения. Я выше описал возможное решение, прийти к которому я не могу в КОДЕ

Comment: *"У меня все вертится и крутится как нужно."* - нет, у вас все вертится и крутится через одно место. Если вы хотите двигать квадрат относительно куба, то поворот и положение куба в этом не должны участвовать. Они должны применяться отдельно, как я описывал в предыдущем коментарии.

Comment: @user7860670 Стоп, подождите, куба не существует. На сцене вы видите только плоскости. Тут просто меняется indexBuffer и все

Comment: @user7860670 т.е сам куб это не отдельный меш, он состоит из 6 мешей, которые я путем трансформаций соединяю в куб

Comment: Это не важно, суть в том, что логически они относятся к кубу.

Comment: @user7860670 Т.е мне нужно создать еще одну матрицу для центра куба, центр у меня в (1,1)
Потом я поворачию эту матрицу и умножаю ее на матрицу каждой из плоскостей ? В таком случае плоскости сами мне поворачивать не нужно, ведь так ? Они остаются в исходном положении, так?

Comment: @user7860670 Если я правильно все понял, то я вроде делаю все то же самое в функции rotate

Comment: Нет, в функции rotate делается совершенно не то. Она начинается с translate, которая использует orign.

Comment: @user7860670 Тогда, пожалуйста, если не сложно, можете объяснить как мне действовать корректно. Создам я матрицу куба, которая изначально является матрицой идентичности. Как только я захочу повернуть весь свой куб, я этот куб поворачиваю относительно какой точки? Относительно (0, 0, 0 ) (У меня ведь центр куба в (1, 1, 1))? Допустим с этим мы разобрались, далее что мне нужно сделать? Повернутую матрицу куба умножить на все rotatationMatrix в плоскостях?

Comment: Поворачиваете и перемещаете квадрат относительно куба, затем поворачиваете и перемещаете сам куб, затем перемножаете результаты.

Comment: @user7860670 Так я это понимаю, мне не особо понятно, как вращать несуществующий куб. Создал я матрицу идентичности для куба, мне нужно куб расположить в точке (1, 1, 1).  Делаю транслейт, делаю поворот, возвращаю обратно. Умножаю на матрицу поворота плоскости -> 0 эффекта

Comment: @user7860670 относительное перемещение и вращение это же по сути просто перемножение матриц

Comment: @user7860670 Можете просто привести пример, потому что я не могу понять корректно вашу мысль в плане исполнения. 
1. Создаем матрицу идентичности для куба. 
2. Куда мы его перемещаем потом, на какую позицию? Куда мне делать translate, в центр куба ? 
3.Поворачиваю матрицу куба
4. Умножаем матрицу куба на матрицу плоскости

Comment: "Делаю транслейт, делаю поворот, возвращаю обратно." сначала поворот, затем транслейт в координаты центра куба (относительно которого перемещаются квадраты), а возвращать обратно ничего не нужно (оно и не вернется обратно после поворота)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137091/discussion-between---and-user7860670).